# What's the explanation for {} as an arrow function version of JavaScript IIFE?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions, iife

The normal arrow function version of an IIFE is this:

```
(() => {
  console.log('IIFE 1');
})();
```

But [I've found here](https://jack.ofspades.com/es6-iife-with-fat-arrow-functions/) that also the following (really short) form works:

> As a bit of extra credit there's an even shorter way to write IIFEs in
>   ES6 which is to use the new function context syntax all on its own
>   like so:

```
{
  console.log('IIFE 2');
}
```

Why only `{}` is enought?

Comment: That's not an IIFE. The blog is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first example creates a *function* (which calls `console.log`), then immediately calls it.

The second example doesn't create a function. It just has a [block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block).

Comment: So... it's just a... simple block what is parsed like any other block (example, the `if` one) just without any keyword?

Comment: @gremo — Yes. Just a block.

Answer (score 0):

Well what's the point of calling an IIFE? it's to run some code in it's own context, right?

Thats what curly brackets do, they group blocks of code. From ES6, variables declared with `const`or `let` are not available from outside a block of code. So

```
(() => {
  var x = 'IIFE 1'
  console.log(x);
})();
```

and

```
{
  let x = 'IIFE 1'
  console.log(x);
}
```

are equivalent

Answer (score -2):

Because it satisfies both conditions required by an IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression):

- To prevent external access to the variables within the IIFE, as well as avoid polluting the global scope.
- It is executed immediately.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE

The only limitation, as the author indicates, is that you can't pass external parameters to the block.

Comment: Thanks but not what I'm asking. I know and I use IIFE for create a local scope.

Comment: {} is not an arrow function, if that is what you ask. I don't see the blog says that either.